# Fabric.js Path object not selectable because of width and height

Tags: svg, fabricjs

Using fabric.js I create a Path object like so:

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.backgroundColor = '#f5f5f5';
var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 20 Q 50 100 100 20',{
    stroke: 'black',
    fill: ''
});
canvas.add(path);
```

This works as expected, however, the user can not move the path on canvas. When you hover over the path, you will see that you do not get the "move" cursor, you can not move the path.

I believe that this is a result of the path having a height of 0. Why does this path have a height of 0, despite there being a control point that gives the path height?

Here's a fiddle to show what I mean. As you can see in the console log, the path has a height of 0, and so does the bounding rectangle. Is this a bug or expected behavior?

http://jsfiddle.net/flyingL123/0j2q9uf9/5/

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or intended behaviour. Although you can use the `padding` property to increase space between object and controlling borders. That way you will be able to select and move the path you created.
Just add padding:50 while initializing the path.

Comment: please be sure that you use correct fabric version. that path is correctly selectable since some revision.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi can you be more specific? I'm using `1.4.13`, which is the latest release from what I can tell.

Comment: @SwapnilJain thanks for the suggestion, but this does not result in the shape being centered in the bounding box, so it won't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload fabric.js version to `1.4.13`. You can download here: https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.backgroundColor = '#f5f5f5';
var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 20 Q 50 100 100 20',{
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    stroke: 'black',
    fill: ''
});

canvas.add(path);
console.log(path);
console.log(path.getBoundingRect());
```

I have uploaded your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0j2q9uf9/7/

It works like a charm.

Comment: Ah whoops, I see now that I had the wrong version of fabric in the fiddle. I do have `1.4.3` in my app, and it's not working for me, so it must be something else in my app causing the problem. I will try to narrow it down and then ask a separate question if needed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For the record, here is the follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011717/update-fabric-js-path-points-dynamically. It looks like the issue is with dynamically adding points to a path. The bounding rectangle does not get updated.