# Click events on complex canvas shapes without recourse to external libraries

Tags: canvas, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'd like to implement click detection for multiple complex shapes on a single canvas element similar to that as realized by `CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath()`.

Obligatory example code below.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<p>In path: <code id="result">false</code></p>
```

JS:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const result = document.getElementById('result');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(25, 25);
ctx.lineTo(105, 25);
ctx.lineTo(25, 105);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(125, 45);
ctx.lineTo(45, 125);
ctx.lineTo(125, 125);
ctx.lineTo(205, 45);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
result.innerText = `${ctx.isPointInPath(e.clientX, e.clientY)} X: ${e.clientX} Y: ${e.clientY}`;
});
```

While the above works well for the last drawn shape, I'd like to be able to perform the same check for any previously drawn shapes.

The project I am working on involves selecting different tiles on an isometric map, so I would like to receive as much information about the selected tile as I can once that tile is clicked on.

I'd rather not have to resort to rendering SVGs due to the amount of shapes I intend to draw. Also, external libraries are undesired and I'm hesitant to draw a pseudo canvas for every shape I draw on the 'visible' canvas just to be able to detect clicks. What alternatives are out there other than waiting for hit regions to come out of experimental status?

I came across a similar, but ultimately different question here: [complex shape selection on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368225/complex-shape-selection-on-canvas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`isPointInPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) accepts a [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/) object as optional first argument.

So an easy way is to create such Path2D objects for each of your shapes.
It can even ease your drawing operations, since `fill()` and `stroke()` also accept these objects:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const result = document.getElementById('result');

const shape1 = new Path2D();
shape1.moveTo(25, 25);
shape1.lineTo(105, 25);
shape1.lineTo(25, 105);

const shape2 = new Path2D();
shape2.moveTo(125, 45);
shape2.lineTo(45, 125);
shape2.lineTo(125, 125);
shape2.lineTo(205, 45);
shape2.closePath();

// to render it
ctx.fill(shape1);
ctx.fill(shape2);

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
result.textContent = `
  shape1: ${ctx.isPointInPath(shape1, e.offsetX, e.offsetY)}
  shape2: ${ctx.isPointInPath(shape2, e.offsetX, e.offsetY)}
  X: ${e.offsetX} Y: ${e.offsetY}`;
});
```

```css
.log { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div class="log">In path: <pre id="result">false</pre></div>
```